# `init()` vs declaration in Go

Tags: go, initialization

I'm having a little trouble understanding why `init()` is useful in Go. It seem that generally, anything you do in `init()` could be done via a declaration in the go file instead.

To put a fine point on, what's the practical difference between these two files?

```
// useInit.go

package main

var answer int

func init() {
    answer = 42
}
```

```
// useDeclaration.go

package main

var answer int = 42
```

Comment: Not every package is `main`. Have you looked at any of the many uses of `init` in the std library? Just picking a `func init()` at random: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.2:src/crypto/sha512/sha512.go

Comment: Thought experiment: If I comment out lines 20 and 25, does this package still work? I'm under the impression it does, which would make the `init` superfluous. Is that not right?

Comment: Removing _only_ lines 20 and 25 would move those calls outside of a function body, which is invalid. Removing the whole function prevents the `sha512` functions from being registered with the `crypto` package. [Another example](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.2:src/crypto/rand/rand_unix.go;l=30) might be when you want to assign a package variable based on some condition, which you also can't do outside of a function body.

Comment: I think that actually answers my question. In the SHA example, you can't run lines 21 to 24 outside of a function. Those functions *only* have side effects and no return value. If they had a return value I could use `var _ = crypto.RegisterHash(crypto.SHA384, New384)` to the same effect. I'd speculate that the difference there has something to do with low-level memory management or compiler concerns or something else that is abstracted away from my day-to-day use.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a package for used in other applications and don't have a main, but you have to do something (and be sure to be done) before the app is running, you can do it in the `init()`. And for this to run, the host app doesn't need to do anything, it doesn't even have to use any func from your package. Good example is the mysql driver (`github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`). It's init() func looks like this:

```
func init() {
    sql.Register("mysql", &MySQLDriver{})
}
```

And when you import it using

```
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

The mysql driver will be registered, so the SQL package can connect to a MySQL server, however you didn't do anything, don't even use a func from this package.

In this case the import name should be an underscore to tell the compiler to not remove the package, however it looks like you don't use it for anything.